# Define Serializer options for ToJson() in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it posible to define serializer for ToJson method for the new feature in entity framework core "Mapping to JSON Columns"

Class:

```cs
public class MyClass {
  public string MyInnerPropety{ get; set; }
}
```

Inside context model builder

```cs
builder.OwnsOne(m => m.MyClassProperty, ownedNavigationBuilder =>{
  ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
});
```

Currently as default serializer is serializing as CapitalCase I would like to use camelCase for property names since that is JSON standard and I am not sure why MS is pushing it to be CapitalCase but that is issue for another question.

Current:

```json
{ "MyInnerPropety": "Test"}
```

Wanted:

```json
{ "myInnerPropety": "Test"}
```

Comment: Your model looks strange, Json Column is usually used for navigation properties,have you tried with ownedNavigationBuilder.Property(....).HasJsonPropertyName("")methoed?

Comment: I will try to use json property on the model thank you that is good idea. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-ef7-release-candidate-2/ i was using this feature

Comment: @RuikaiFeng Actually my bad   [JsonPropertyName("myInnerPropety")] works just fine I would like to be able to define this globaly but this is fine for now. If you would like to add an answer I will mark it as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try add `JsonPropertyName` attribute on the attribute or configure in
OnModelCreate method

Comment: Yes and you can also vote for https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28043 here so that  we can do this globaly.

Comment: This is a bad answer for people coming to look for a way to configure the JSON serializer options for entity framework.

Answer (score 1):

They introduced a new method [HasJsonPropertyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotNet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hasjsonpropertyname?view=efcore-7.0) to use in JSON configuration instead of `HasColumnName`

```
builder.OwnsOne(entity => entity.MyClassProperty, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
{
    ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();

    ownedNavigationBuilder
        .Property(x => x.MyInnerPropety)
        .HasJsonPropertyName("myInnerPropety")
});
```